# Docker Tutorial: Nginx webserver returns 403 (Forbidden) Error

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm new to Docker, so I decided to go through the [tutorial for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#explore-the-application). I'm getting stuck on the "Explore the application" segment where I run a Dockerized nginx web server. When I try to open the webserver in Chrome, I get a 403 Forbidden Error:

[image]

I have looked though StackOverflow and googled this issue, every question involving this 403 issue is solved using components that I haven't seen in the tutorial. My goal is to get the "Welcome to nginx!" page when I enter `localhost` in my web browser.

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise, with Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24.

Edit: Following some advice in the comments, I've printed the config file here. I'm not sure where the bad configuration is though.

```
[
    {
        "Id": "67de198556e7da0e9b71e57650246d08506b4c49968ba1c87627513ffee41a79",
        "Created": "2018-04-07T20:29:48.9119428Z",
        "Path": "nginx",
        "Args": [
            "-g",
            "daemon off;"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 3537,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2018-04-07T20:29:49.6956743Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:c5c4e8fa2cf7d87545ed017b60a4b71e047e26c4ebc71eb1709d9e5289f9176f",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/67de198556e7da0e9b71e57650246d08506b4c49968ba1c87627513ffee41a79/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/67de198556e7da0e9b71e57650246d08506b4c49968ba1c87627513ffee41a79/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/67de198556e7da0e9b71e57650246d08506b4c49968ba1c87627513ffee41a79/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/67de198556e7da0e9b71e57650246d08506b4c49968ba1c87627513ffee41a79/67de198556e7da0e9b71e57650246d08506b4c49968ba1c87627513ffee41a79-json.log",
        "Name": "/webserver",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                50,
                250
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c273414203bb1d24f7fbcae3d0e59cc5862177ebd8f76b36932e34906a62451e-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6c92d8da4b6dc602aec458c26ea89f896e8f1419669fde38695b4a8536e1b5eb/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ba798be7f037f7a409573831d1c97c8ce6364ee5d211203d53ffae65c31356ae/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e64dbbe96402a9a713d35ad3496b47aba1d9f71b158833ea2826f9bafc0c6060/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c273414203bb1d24f7fbcae3d0e59cc5862177ebd8f76b36932e34906a62451e/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c273414203bb1d24f7fbcae3d0e59cc5862177ebd8f76b36932e34906a62451e/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c273414203bb1d24f7fbcae3d0e59cc5862177ebd8f76b36932e34906a62451e/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "67de198556e7",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NGINX_VERSION=1.13.11-1~stretch",
                "NJS_VERSION=1.13.11.0.2.0-1~stretch"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "nginx",
                "-g",
                "daemon off;"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "nginx",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "maintainer": "NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>"
            },
            "StopSignal": "SIGTERM"
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "8441b997d10c187f4f8b1f61e12b44ed7f8b9aff30c19277ef0725deb0266a99",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/8441b997d10c",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "1bfa563ee831522a547b1977a02d068d576e25427d3bc48c4b27ec76775858fc",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "33deae47133f450e63d0e9ded2d0babc1a0b34ce50885a63a01ae18d9e357ddf",
                    "EndpointID": "1bfa563ee831522a547b1977a02d068d576e25427d3bc48c4b27ec76775858fc",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Well, having a 403 it's actually a good thing, it means that the port 80 was successfully linked to the docker container and that nginx is running. I bet is just some misconfiguration within nginx config files

Comment: How do I access and modify the configuration files? What are nginx's proper configurations?

Comment: use `docker inspect`  check the container, it is maybe caused by incorrect volume bindings.

Comment: @zhimin I added the config file to the question

Comment: `VolumeDriver` is blank, `VolumesFrom` and `Volume` is null, what should these values be?

Comment: run `docker run --it YOUR_CONTAINER bash` to run an interactive shell session with your container, then go to `/etc/nginx/sites-avialable` and check for `default` file

Comment: It's not recognizing the `--it` option, I switched it with `-it` and it returned `path\to\docker.exe: Error message from daemon: pull access denied for YOUR_CONTAINER, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.` I used `docker login`, I put in my credentials and tried the command again but still got the same error.